# Google Sheets API V4 - Autofill Error - No grid with id: 0

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am trying to make an [AutoFillRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#autofillrequest) using a [SourceAndDestination](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#SourceAndDestination) object to describe the area to autofill. I've tested autofill requests using a GridRange object and everything works fine, but can't seem to get the SourceAndDestination working. Here is an example where I'm trying to autofill down the first row for 2 more rows.

**HTTP POST**

```
https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{spreadsheetId}:batchUpdate
```

**Request Body**

```
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "autoFill": {
        "sourceAndDestination": {
          "dimension": "ROWS",
          "fillLength": 2,
          "source": {
            "sheetId": 1150108545,
            "endRowIndex": 1,
            "startRowIndex": 0
          }
        },
        "useAlternateSeries": false
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The response has an error code 400:

> message = "Invalid requests[0].autoFill: No grid with id: 0" status =
>   "INVALID_ARGUMENT"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry about that, this was a bug on the server. It's now fixed, so the above should work.

Comment: @StevenMortimer -- I forget exactly when the fix rolled out, but the original code should work now.

Comment: I'm experiencing this bug, but only with certain spreadsheets. With some spreadsheets, m exact same code works. With others, the exact same code comes back with: 'Invalid requests[0].addFilterView: No grid with id: 2'. I've verified multiple sources that there is a sheet with an index/id of 2. Can anyone look to see if this bug is occuring again?