# Google Sheets API addProtectedRange Error: No grid with id: 0

Tags: google-sheets-api

I am not sure if I am making a mistake or if possibly this is related to the same issue reported here:

[Google Sheets API V4 - Autofill Error - No grid with id: 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43395032/google-sheets-api-v4-autofill-error-no-grid-with-id-0/43398026#43398026)

I am getting:

*HttpError 400

 "Invalid requests[0].addProtectedRange: No grid with id: 1"*

Code is something like this (additional addProtectedRange objects removed)

```
def add_protected_ranges(spreadsheet_id):
    service = get_sheets_service()

    requests = [
    {
        "addProtectedRange": {
            'protectedRange': {
                "range": {
                    "sheetId": 1,
                    "startRowIndex": 0,
                    "endRowIndex": 0,
                    "startColumnIndex": 0
                },
                "description": "Headers must not be changed",
                "warningOnly": True
            }
        }
        }

    ]

    body = {
        'requests': requests
    }
    response = service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id,
                                              body=body).execute()
```

Answer (score 23):

Had kind of the same issue. I was confusing the *sheet id* with *sheet index*.

Easiest way to find the ***sheet id*** is in the browser URL when you open the spreadsheet / sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/**{spreadsheetId}**/edit#gid=**{sheetId}**

If you're looking for a more programmatic way you find that property on the [SheetProperties](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#sheetproperties).

Comment: @PatrickRainsberry How did you get sheetId???  I get this error even if I omit "sheetId" from the range field!  I've never ever specified a sheet id in the browser, so I don't see how that could even help figure it out, because you have to know it before you can enter it as an URL!

Comment: I think maybe you are confusing sheetId and spreadsheetId.  In this case I needed the sheetId.  Most operations require the spreadsheetId. You don’t need a sheetId to open the document in the browser.

Comment: For more info on the `sheetId` property, see https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts#sheet_id

Answer (score 5):

I know that's an old question but I was looking for it too. You're looking for:

```
res.data.sheets[].properties.sheetId
```

To get the `sheetId` (not the `spreadsheetId`) use:

```
sheets.spreadsheets.get({
  spreadsheetId
}).then(res => {
  console.log("All the sheets:");
  for(i in res.data.sheets) {
    let title = res.data.sheets[i].properties.title;
    let id = res.data.sheets[i].properties.sheetId;
    console.log(title + ': ' + id);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that there is a workbook with the id 1 in your spreadsheet. In google sheet, a spreadsheet can contain multiple worksheet(grid), there is a unique id for each of the worksheet(grid).